# Firebase Firestore - Limit results per page

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of photo ID's in Firebase. I would like to limit the number of results returned from a Firebase Cloud Firestore query to 25 per page, then when the site viewer clicks a "next page" button it will show the next 25 in the order.

I have used the code below from the Firebase documentation to limit the query but I am unsure how to start the second query at the position the previous one finished (e.g. item number 26, then item number 51...).

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
var photosRef = db.collection("photos");
photosRef.where("approved", "==", true).limit(3);
```

Thank you

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the query cursors: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

```
photosRef.where("approved", "==", true).limit(3).startAfter(3);
```